# How to turn the String of the name of a Column in SQLAlchemy in Pythonn into the Column to send Data

Tags: python, database, string, sqlalchemy

Hi im trying to create an abstract methode that gets an Object of my Database model i want to use and then can assign data to some specific columns inside of it.

The names of the columns i get as a List of Strings from another table.

models is my dictionary filled with my models as values and the tablenames as their keys

```
db = session.query(Model_tables).filter(Model_tables.ID == 4).all()

for table in db:
    x = str(table.table_name)
    

   if x in models:
        table = models.get(x)

   new = table(column_strings[0]=1, column_strings[1]=2)

session.add(new)
session.commit()
```

Is there a way of doing it like this?

Comment: You would make a dictionary mapping column names to values and then do `new = table(**my_dict)`.